# How hard is it to stake a vampire?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

For staking a vampire through the heart in Pathfinder, what type of DC value or combat method should be used in order to perform the staking?

Comment: Great! Thank you for the quick answer!! I love this site!

Comment: You should accept the answer if it answers your question. Click the little check mark under the score on the answer.

Answer (score 15):

The description of the [Vampire](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/vampire.html#_vampire) says you can stake one if its helpless.

The rules are optional, but Ultimate Combat does have rules for [Called Shots](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/variants/calledShots.html#_heart). According to those rules, hitting the heart is a -10 to an attack. Staking a vamp is specifically listed, and requires either a Crit or damage equal to half the vampire's hit points (min 50...), which forces a Fort save or be staked.